# enabling and disabling tap gesture recognizer from a void Xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uigesturerecognizer

I guess the title says the most but here are some specific details

I have a textbox and when I click it, it opens a keypad that helps you put numbers on the textbox

I put the tapgesture recognizer to close the keypad and it works but I put it into the ViewDidLoad method. I want to Enable the GestureRecognizer to be enabled when the keypad is opened and disable itself when i closed the keypad. I need this because tap recognizer delays the touches on the screen.

In the `ViewDidLoad` I call the method using

```
[self gestureenablingvoid];
and in the gestureenablingvoid I use this
    if (textfield.isEditing) {
     //code that generates tapgesture
    }
```

But it does not work as I want it to be.

So thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using `touchesBegan:withEvent:` instead of a gesture recognizer for an easier solution:

```
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    [yourUITextFieldName resignFirstResponder];
}
```

With this method added to your ViewController the keypad should disappear when you touch outside it.